# How to bundle external script & font properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to bundle 1 external script & 2 external google fonts but having issues with correctly bundling them.

These are the ones i'm trying to bundle:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

In my BundleConfig I have enabled usecdn and created 3 cdnPath's as showed below:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;

var cdnPath1 = "~/http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
var cdnPath2 = "~/http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic";
var cdnPath3 = "~/http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,700,900";

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/topjs").Include(
                                    cdnPath1));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/fonts").Include(
                                    cdnPath2,
                                    cdnPath3));
```

I have rendered them in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/fonts")
```

The problem is that the external javascript file and the 2 google fonts are not working and not showing up.

Comment: Add this line - BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; and use correct render paths - @Styles.Render("~/Content/fonts")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/topjs")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bundle multiple cdns. only local files can be bundled together
Check these links:
http://venkatbaggu.com/use-cdn-bundle-config-in-asp-net-mvc/
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification (check Using a CDN header)